# Google Places fields aren't being filled in automatic

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

We have Google Places Api on our site.
When the api is being initialized, the fields affected are being set `autocomplete="off"`.
How can I make that fields able to the browser autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Place Autocomplete service for that by placing an autocomplete request at

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/output?parameters
```

Refer https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete for a complete guide, it also illustrates how to use location biasing and restrictions.